# How to make the outer <div> fixed while the inner <div> is scroll-able using the main window vertical scroll bar

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

Please look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/sS7HN/2/

What I am trying to achieve is instead of that inner scroll-bar, I want to use the main window scroll bar; So that I can use the windows vertical scroll bar to go through the content inside the `innerContent` but at the same time I want the outer div ( `content` and `mainContent` ) to be fixed.

Is that possible?

**CSS**

```css
#header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    background-color:#656565;
    width: 300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
}

#mainContent {
    margin:0px auto;
    background-color:#515151;
    width:250px;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding-top:20px;
}

#contentHolder {
    color:#fff;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:200px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:#000000;
    border-radius:10px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">cfdvfvdfvfv</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="mainContent">
        <div id="contentHolder">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam dictum imperdiet lacus in aliquet. Nam leo
            risus, bibendum vel varius non, porta vel orci. Integer scelerisque est eu augue tempus lfvdvdfvuctus.
            Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus vulputate dolor ligula.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383394/how-to-make-inner-div-use-window-scroll-bar

Comment: @azhrei in that example the borders will not be rounded correctly

Answer (score 0):

@Daedalus wrote some jQuery for this in [this answer to a question similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626503/scroll-an-overflowing-div-by-scrolling-anywhere-on-the-page).

The jQuery code is below (Edit: changed it to match your code):

```
var curScroll = 0;

$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
    var evt = window.event || e;
    var delta = evt.detail? evt.detail*(-120) : evt.wheelDelta;
    if(delta < 0) {
        //scroll down
        curScroll += 10;
    }
    else {
        //scroll up
        curScroll -= 10;
    }
    $('#contentHolder').scrollTop(curScroll);
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment above, a [CSS based example is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383394/how-to-make-inner-div-use-window-scroll-bar).

You also wanted rounded corners. You can do that by giving the content a bit of extra padding, and then adding some `fixed` page edges on the top and bottom of it.

[Modified sample, with rounded corners](http://jsfiddle.net/7pcFm/3/)

The key bits there are:

```
#content {
    padding: 120px 150px; /* the 120px is the overlay vert height + 10px + 10px */
}
.page_horiz_strip {
    position:fixed;
    left: 150px;
    right: 150px;
    height: 10px;
    background: white;
}
.top_rounded {
    top: 90px; /* 10px less than the overlay vert height */
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}
.bottom_rounded {
    bottom: 90px; /* 10px less than the overlay vert height */
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

**Notes**

- I'm adding a 10px high strip on the top and bottom of the content
  (and rounding the strips).
- The overlay vertical height is 100px.
- Therefore the content padding needs to increase to 100px + 10px +
  10px.
- The strips thus need to be 90px away from the page edge, not
  100px.